# A practice neural network to find maximum values from subset

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, deep-learning, function-approximation

I have an input vector of shape say 1 x 400. It's fed into a network that outputs a 1 x 100 vector. I want to design a model that only considers every 4th value of this tensor and gives me the max values.

For example, a demo tensor could be `[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 3, 0.7, 0.2, 0.6, 8, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 12, 0.7, 0.1, 0.9, 12]`. For this 1x16 input, the corresponding output would be a 1x4 one. I want the model to look only at values `3,8,12,12` and then predict an output of the following form `0,0,1,1`. (note that there could be more than 1 1s in the output)

I have tried using MLPs to do this using CELoss but to no avail. Can this be solved using some particular architecture/loss only or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Why aren't you just creating an input vector with every fourth value?

Comment: Every 4th element of $[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 3, 0.7, 0.2, 0.6, 8, 0.3, 0.1, 0.5, 12, 0.7, 0.1, 0.9, 8]$ would be $[3,8,12,8]$, not $[3,8,12,12]$.

Comment: I agree with @Brian O'Donnell.  The question is unclear.  It is also unclear why do you need a model to input every 4th element?  This is simply a preprocessing operation.  Second, why do you need a model to return binary coded output of max $1$ vs. not max $0$.?  This can be done with good old fashioned argmax operations, etc.

Comment: so to summarize, your problem does not required any complicated model, just a few lines of processing code can do.

Comment: I understand it seems like a preprocessing problem (and it actually is). I was trying to understand if NNs can learn such functions if designed properly, given that I have a lot of training examples of the above form.

Answer (score 1):

Even though (as discussed above) this problem is best handled by pre- and post-processing, **yes**, a neural network can be used for this problem.  *One possible way* to do it is as follows:

1. Create your training data.
   The features `x_train` ($x_i\ \in\mathbb{R}^{400}$) will be the input vectors.
   The labels `y_train` ($y_i\ \in\mathbb{R}^{100}$) will be derived by subsetting the input vectors to include every 4th element of $x_i$ and then setting the max values $= 1$ and all others $= 0$.

```
# The below (python) code illustrates how this can be done

import numpy as np
x = np.random.randn(400)
y = x[::4]
idx = np.argwhere(y == max(y))
y = np.zeros_like(y)
y[idx] = 1
```

2. Architect and train a neural network with 400 input units and 100 output units.  You can try different hyperparameters, starting with simple models first.  The choice of loss function can also be a hyperparameter, but you can try common loss functions like crossentropy loss (CEL) and root mean squared error (RMSE) first.
3. The output units can have a sigmoid activation so that all the values are **between $0$ and $1$**.  I'm not sure how well a unit step function would work here as an activation function, but that would guarantee that the values are **either $0$ or $1$**.  With the unit step function, there is no need for post-processing.  You can experiment with both.
4. If you use a sigmoid activation, then you will still need to do some post-processing to ensure that the final values in the output vector are $0$ or $1$. For example, you can set values $>0.95 = 1$ and all others $= 0$.